# How are curved quads rendered efficiently?

Tags: performance, 3d, rendering, mesh, topology

A common industry standard is to utilize quads rather than triangles or ngons in 3d topology.

I understand that quads deform better and can be subdivided easily but I have noticed nearly all professional models have quads with curved lines.

To my understanding, curved lines must be broken down into many triangles which would mean a higher poly count which is generally a bad thing.

How are curved quads rendered such that they are preferred over triangles?

EDIT: Below are two examples of the geometry I'm referring to

[image: example]

Comment: Could you provide definition of a "curved quad"? I find the term not self-explanatory.

Comment: @MauricioCeleLopezBelon I added some pictures for clarity

Comment: I suspect the "curved quads" are probably NURBS https://en.m.wikipedia.org/wiki/Non-uniform_rational_B-spline Could you confirm that?

Comment: Quads are preferred over triangles for *modeling*. The reason is a simpler topology, which makes it easier to model and easier to tessellate the mesh. This has nothing to do with performance. In fact, as you said yourself, for rendering purposes they are converted back to triangles ('triangulated').

Comment: @YakovGalka I guess my point is that by using quads that are not all at 90 degree angles (or at least appear to not be) the model will ultimately require more triangles and is therefore higher poly and heavier. This contradicts the idiom that using quads creates better or lighter geometry.

Comment: @stackoverflow909 never heard anybody saying that "using quads creates lighter geometry". Can you give a source for that claim so one could base an answer off that?

Comment: @YakovGalka I might be overstepping with lighter but quads are the industry standard despite the fact that, to my understanding, the curved lines in many quads would make the models drastically heavier.